# Create configurable product magento 2 Programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, catalog-product

Create Programmatically configurable & simple product

Comment: You can follow this : https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-create-configurable-product-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: This is Great answer

Comment: Should I need to update as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how configurable & simple product can be created in magento 2 https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html

Comment: is it required to run the file with this code directly from root folder ?

Comment: Yes ,directly from root folder of magento setup.